# Regex find start than any char before finding end

Tags: javascript, regex

Please help me with this:

I have a batch of links in string, like

```
http://hw-img.website.com/photo/01252018.jpg
http://hw-img.website.com/photo/21212015.jpg
http://hw-img.website.com/photo/11162012.jpg
```

I need find all:

```
hw-img*com/

find start 'hw-img' than any char before finding end 'com/'
```

and replace all founded with "newsite.com/hw-img/" to get

```
http://website.com/hw-img/photo/01252018.jpg
http://website.com/hw-img/photo/21212015.jpg
http://website.com/hw-img/photo/11162012.jpg
```

What regular expression I need to write to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your `input` is a single string (with embedded newlines), then this snippet should produce the desired result:

```
input.replace(/hw-img.*?com\//g, 'newsite.com/hw-img/')
```